# Compatible initial condition for the numerical scheme of PDE

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

I have to solve numerically the following PDE ($0<t_0<t$):
$$\partial_t H(x,t,t_0) = \partial_x^2 H(x,t,t_0)+(1-2U(x,t))H(x,t,t_0)$$
with the initial condition:
$$H(x,t=t_0,t_0) = U^2(x,t_0)$$
The numerical scheme I use is implicit,
$$\frac{H^{n+1}_{k}-H^{n}_{k}}{dt} = \frac{H^{n+1}_{k+1}-2H^{n+1}_{k}+H^{n+1}_{k-1}}{dx^2} + (1-2U^{n+1}_{k})H^{n+1}_{k}$$
where U is a function which I know the numerical solution at every time step from 0 to t.

Question: What should be the initial condition to be used for this scheme?

1. $ H^0_k = (U^0_k)^2 $ ?
2. $ H^0_k = (U^0_{k+1})^2 $ ?
3. $ H^0_k = U^0_{k+1} U^0_k $ ?

Indeed, I tried the first one, but the result seems not correct.

P/s: $dx = 0.5$ and $dt = 0.1$

Comment: Indeed it should be (1). Why is the discretization for $2U(x,t) = U_k^{n+1}$? Assuming the loss of $2$ was just a typo, shouldn't we be looking at $U_k^n$?

Comment: I assume you went off to test it; in case I forget to look back at this later but other things you look at: (1) Make sure you're meeting the CFL conditions on $\Delta x, \Delta t$. (2) Test using the convergence via method of Manufactured Solutions. (3) When in doubt, rederive and recode the whole thing.

Comment: @TrostAft I've added the values of dx and dt I used. I don't think there is a problem with convergence.

Comment: How about the recommended change from $U^{n+1}_k$ to $U^n_k$? It isn't correct to step forward that value in time when using an implicit solver; just the values for $H$.